# app has stopped in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2016-11-16 16:46:35 - HoppingBird] Device API version is 17 (Android 4.2.2)
[2016-11-16 16:46:35 - HoppingBird] Uploading HoppingBird.apk onto device '42037515b433b100'
[2016-11-16 16:46:37 - HoppingBird] Installing HoppingBird.apk...
[2016-11-16 16:46:43 - HoppingBird] Success!
[2016-11-16 16:46:48 - google-play-services_lib_ext] Could not find google-play-services_lib_ext.apk!
[2016-11-16 16:46:48 - HoppingBird] Starting activity com.dev.hopping.MainActivity on device 42037515b433b100
[2016-11-16 16:46:51 - HoppingBird] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.dev.hopping/.MainActivity }

Comment: Its just a warning and it says Install success. Further it is opening Main Afctivity. What is the issue? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Google hasn't supported Android development for a long time. I recommend you migrate your Project to Android Studio

Comment: Dear LoveForDroid, the app is installed but it doesn't work i have that message app has unfortunately stopped and in the console i have this message Could not find google-play-services_lib_ext.apk! and my phone already have it

Comment: Will Evers, can i upload my project to android studio with no errors cause in this project i dont have gradle section ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you tried referencing Google Play Services Library by adding it in project properties. You do not need to do that. Just remove it from there. You only need google-play-services_lib.jar. After that just clean and build.

Comment: You right click on project and goto properties then you will find an option of Java Build Path. Under that their is a ' libraries' tab. You can add the library there

Comment: i did that but i have this error : 
Project  is missing required Java project: 'google-play-services_lib_ext'   Build Path Problem